# Combine 2 array lists of objects that have null values

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to concatenate 2 array lists of objects into one but i can't figure out how to do it. I've tried with addAll and add but those methods won't really do what i want.
Basically, i have one array list with values like this:

```
SearchResult1 [title=null, url=null, price=19 690 EUR]
```

And another one with values like this:

```
SearchResult2 [title=Ford Car, url=http://www.something.com, price=null]
```

How can i combine those 2 arrays into one with values like this:

```
SearchResult3 [title=Ford Car, url=http://www.something.com, price=19 690 EUR]
```

This is the code so far:

```
  public List searchMethod() {
                try {
                    final String query = "ford";

                    final Document page = Jsoup.connect("link" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8")).userAgent(USER_AGENT).get();

                     List<SearchResult> resultList1 = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();
                     List<SearchResult> resultList2 = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();
                     List<SearchResult> resultList3 = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();


                    for(Element searchResult : page.select(".offer-price")) {
                         String price = searchResult.text();
                         resultList1.add(new SearchResult(price));
                    }

                    for(Element searchResult : page.select(".offer-title__link")) {
                         String title = searchResult.text();
                         String url = searchResult.attr("href");
                         resultList2.add(new SearchResult(title, url));
                    }
                    resultList3.addAll(resultList1);
                    resultList3.addAll(resultList2);

                    return resultList3;

                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return Collections.emptyList();

        }
```

The values that i put in those arrays are extracted from a web page
Thanks for helping!

Comment: On what basis/criteria will you merge?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The objects in your first list has only price and objects in the second list has URL and title. How will you combine them?

Comment: Yeah but the class SearchResult has 3 constructors. One with price, one with title and url and one with price,url and title

Comment: I need to merge the values from the first and the second array into one array where title, price and url are all one entry

Comment: Does both list have the same size? So, do you want to correlate/join/merge by each index of the list?

Comment: Yes, i want to correlate by each index of the list and yes the arrays have the same size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159691/combine-2-array-lists-of-objects-that-have-null-values?noredirect=1#comment89303266_51159691), you have said that you just want to correlate/merge the objects from both lists by each index.

You can simply loop through the list, constructing a new `SearchResult` (assuming you have getters for the fields)

```
for(int i = 0; i < resultList1.size(); i++) {
    resultList3.add(new SearchResult(resultList1.get(i).getPrice(),
                   resultList2.get(i).getTitle(),
                   resultList2.get(i).getUrl()));
}
```

You may have to change the order of the passed arguments to the `SearchResult` constructor taking `price`, `title` and `url` as you haven't shown it.

Comment: It looks like it works! Thanks and sorry for not knowing how to explain the problem in a clear way :(

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do it in one shot?

```
List<SearchResult> resultList1 = new ArrayList<SearchResult>();
for(Element searchResult : page.select(".offer-title__link")) {
    String title = searchResult.text();
    String url = searchResult.attr("href");
    resultList1.add(new SearchResult(title, url));
}
int index = 0;
for(Element searchResult : page.select(".offer-price")) {
    String price = searchResult.text();
    //since you have already assumed 
    //that price will come in the same order and title and url.
    resultList1.get(index++).setPrice(price);
}
return resultList1;
```

Comment: This solution works too! I never thought about doing it like this. Thanks!